# Plotting the magnitude response of a biquad filter

Tags: filters, audio, frequency-response, biquad

I've put together a multi-band audio EQ using biquad filters.  I'm getting the coefficients using the methods from [the RBJ cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).

Now I want to plot the curve showing the magnitude response.  I'm using an equation from [this source](http://rs-met.com/documents/dsp/BasicDigitalFilters.pdf)

Here is my function to get the coefficients and get the magnitude response at points of interest.

```
void GetCoefficients (double samplerate = 44100.0) {

    //from the rbj biquad coefficient cookbook by Robert Bristow-Johnson
    long double SR = (long double)samplerate;
    long double A = powl(10.0L, dBGain/40.0L);
    long double W0 = 2.0L * PI * Center / SR;
    long double alpha = sinl(W0)*sinhl( LN2/2.0L * WidthInOctaves * W0/sinl(W0));

    if (Type == "peaking") {
        b0 = 1.0L + alpha * A;
        b1 = -2.0L * cosl(W0);
        b2 = 1.0L - alpha * A;
        a0 = 1.0L + alpha / A;
        a1 = -2.0L * cosl(W0);
        a2 = 1.0L - alpha / A;
    }
    
    long double w;
    long double numerator;
    long double denominator;
    long double magnitude;

    for (int i = 0; i < 59; ++ i) {
        w = 2.0L*PI*FreqPoints[i] / SR;  
        numerator = b0*b0 + b1*b1 + b2*b2 + 2.0L*(b0*b1 + b1*b2)*cosl(w) + 2.0L*b0*b2*cosl(2.0L*w);
        denominator = 1.0L + a1*a1 + a2*a2 + 2.0L*(a1 + a1*a2)*cosl(w) + 2.0L*a2*cosl(2.0L*w);
        magnitude = sqrtl(numerator / denominator);
        FrequencyResponse[i] = magnitude;   
    }
}
```

My filters sound correct, but my plot seams way wrong.  For example, when I have calculated the coefficients for a peaking filter with a width of $2$ octaves, centered at $4398\textrm{ Hz}$, with $3\textrm{ dB}$ gain; my magnitude response using those coefficients at $349\textrm{ Hz}$ is about $12$.

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: That looks correct to me. There is nothing obviously wrong. Debug hint: try an allpass filter, numerator and denominator should come out to be the same and the a & b's should be fipped, i.e. b2 = a0, b1 = a1, b0 = a2

Comment: It would be best if you showed a complete, compilable example. It's possible that you could have a problem initializing the `FreqPoints` array or the `PI` constant, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone over at the KRV forum pointed out that I need to normalize my coefficients so that a0 = 1.

```
b0 /= a0;
b1 /= a0;
b2 /= a0;
a1 /= a0;
a2 /= a0;
a0 = 1;
```

Comment: hey take a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-do-i-manually-plot-the-frequency-response-of-a-bandpass-butterworth-filter-i/16911#16911).  it shows a numerically better way to plot the magnitude response if you're stuck with using single-precision floats.

Comment: I'm seeing at this old post, and I'm looking for a similar solution, to implement in C#, to plot a curve that represent a parametric filter. I have 10 bands, frequencies and bandwidth for each one, and I need to calc the coordinates (x, y), to add the correct points to draw an accurate curve. Just in case, and seeing at this resolution, Do you have a complete example, including the drawing side, that you could share with me? Thanks!

Comment: @MauricioP. See here for a complete example: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m1m7rhdpda